# Nodejs Is there a way to kill a process then start it again

Tags: node.js

So I'm working on a little project and I want something that lets me restart a process Since I start it by requiring the file so like

```js
switch (start) {
case "-dev":
require("./path/to/file")
break;
}
```

and I want to have a function that when you type `rs` in the console it will restart it without the user needing to run `node . -dev` again. So Something like nodemon but not...

I have this but I don't know how to fully do something like it

```
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout });

let cmd = function () {
  rl.question('', function (answer) {
    switch (answer) {
        case "rs":
            process.exit()
            require("./path/to/file")
    }
    cmd();
  });
};

cmd();
```

but that wouldn't work.. That's why I'm confused

Note: I do not want to use Nodemon

Comment: A process cannot restart itself without the help of some other process (such as nodemon or forever).  So, somewhere you will need some parent process that watches for when the child exits and then restarts it.  On Windows, it could even be a batch file with a loop.  Or, you could make your own mini-node process that does a `child_process.execSync()` and then whenever it exits, it starts it again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named `child_process` on NPM. A function available is `spawn`. The `spawn` command is able to run programs and get output from them. The second there is output, it closes. Note that it opens in a new window. Here is my proposed code to restart your application

```js
var cmd = childprocess.spawn("cmd", [ "/k", "start", "cmd", "/k", "node", ".", "-dev"]);
cmd.stdout.on("data", () => {
  process.exit()
})
```

This feels like a clunky solution, but it does work.

[More information on the child_process module](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html)